# Mongoose Fails to retrieve documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am learning MongoDB+Mongoose+Express right now. And I am facing a bug I can't figure out myself.

**My MongoDB setup (A DB with 2 collections, each has some documents):**
[image: A DB with 2 collections, each has some documents]

**app.js connection to a database:**

```
const dbConnectionString = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost';
mongoose.connect(dbConnectionString + '/blog');
```

**posts.js model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var PostsSchema = new Schema({
    any: {}
});

var Posts = mongoose.model('Posts', PostsSchema);

module.exports = Posts;
```

**blog.js route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Posts = require('../models/posts')

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Route works');
  console.log(Posts);
  Posts.find((err,posts) => {
    if( err ) return console.log('DB Error', err);
    console.log('Posts Received', posts);
    res.render('blog', { title: 'My Blog', posts : posts });  
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

when I run mongodb and node server, accessing it successfully console.logs Schema and

```
Route works
Posts Received []
```

So while the connection to a database seem to work(I don't get errors) I can't get the data from it. I know that I am missing something obvious due to the lack of knowledge but my search through mongoose docs didn't help. Please advise and thank you for your help!

Comment: try  passing an empty object to find as first argument . `Posts.find({} , (err,posts) => { ..`

Comment: same result; Route works, Schema, [] for Posts Received

Comment: You have to define schema attributes. Something like `var PostsSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String
});`

Comment: I changed it to the attributes you specified and still get empty array. I also don't think I have to define them to make it work.

Comment: You are right about the schema attribute. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing any object to find.

The find function in mongoose requires a query parameter. If you need to retrieve the whole collection, you can pass an empty object:

```
MongooseSchema.find({},callback)
```

The first object is the query. You can use some selectors there too. For example, let's say you want everyone with a determined title, in that case you can do something like:

```
MongooseSchema.find({title:"title"},callback)
```

For more than one query parameter, you can separate by commas:

```
MongooseSchema.find({title:"title",subtitle:"subtitle"},callback)
```

and so on. I recommend you taking a look at the mongoose manual part on this matter:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

[Update]

The problem in this case was that mongoose naming conventions were not matching the names used by you. Mongoose does queries in lower-case names, and in this case did not find the Posts collection because of the upper-case P in the beginning of the name. It was solved by changing by 'posts', all in lower-case.

Just a second reminder, mongoose also pluralizes the names when creating collections, so one should be also aware of this fact when creating collections in mongodb.

Reference by @veeram:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Comment: Your answer seem correct. However I've added an empty object as a first parameter to .find and still Posts received is an empty array.

I noticed that in your example you use db.colelction.find, which is how I'd write it in mongodb console. However in my Mongoose I write Posts.find(), while Posts is a Mongoose Schema (see code in question). Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Did you try to print both? err and posts? Sometimes I interchange them by accident (and I still don't remember the order)

Comment: Yes, it prints both and the order is correct:


Posts.find({}, (err,posts) => {
    if( err ) return console.log('DB Error', err);
    console.log('Posts Received', posts);
    res.render('blog', { title: 'My Blog', posts : posts });  
  });

Comment: I GET: TypeError: Posts.findAll is not a function
CODE:  
Posts.findAll().then((posts, data) => {
    console.log('Posts', posts);
    console.log('Data', data);
  });

Comment: My bad, it was an internal function of mine. Instead of findAll, put .find({}).exec(.....)

Comment: POSTS NULL, DATA []. Route works
(node:6304) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise l                  ibrary) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoose                  js.com/docs/promises.html
Posts null
Data []

Comment: I start to suspect that there's a name inconsistency with your db and your mongoose. Please, instead of retriving, make a small code to save one sample post in your database and see how it goes. If it is saved in the correct collection. You might be getting the correct result, but connecting to the wrong collection (It happened to me once).

Comment: Hmm, very interesting, I wrote a simple post request. And I did go through, however it created a 'posts' collection in blog db. So now my db has 'Posts', 'posts' and 'blog' collection. And I can retrieve the created document from lowercase posts collection. Why did it try to refer to a lowercase posts? Where do I specify the name of the collection it should refer to?

Comment: Mongoose sometimes 'does stuff for you' even if you don't want. Be aware of the plural in names too. It is so 'kind' that it puts everything in the plural without even telling you. I never gave much thought about it, just use it as it is and be calm. I will add this problem to my answer in case someone else run into the same problem. ;-)

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection to force collection name to the schema.

Comment: Yep, thank you so much for your help. I think from now on I will always specify the collection name. Already read about the plurals, doesn't seem to me as a legit way to just rely on its quirk and expect it to use the correct collection. Also a good point that the link provided by @Veeram is in "guide", not in Schema part of the docs.